# how to display message throw html page if i enter duplicate values throw html page while error message not displayed

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

If i post values that values are saved in database, in case values duplicate it display the message  like values can not duplicate by rendering html page.in my case values are stored in database but if enter any duplicate values it is throwing the error. how to display message if enter any duplicate values. is there any method method in views.py file

```
1062, "Duplicate entry 'django_post' for key 'title'"
```

Here models.py code

```
 class Post(models.Model):
     title= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     content= models.TextField()
```

view.py file

```
def createpost(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST.get('title') and request.POST.get('content'):
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.POST.get('title')
            post.content = request.POST.get('content')
            post.save()

       return render(request, 'emp.html')
```

emp.html file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Create a Post </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Create a Post </h1>
<form action=" " method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
Title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br/>
Content: <br/>
<textarea cols="35" rows="8" name="content">
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the html file  I want to give the html page after posting the data through html page

duplicate.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Duplicate values are entered</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should change HTML page:

Replace your code:

```
return render(request, 'emp.html')
```

To:

```
return render(request, 'inserted.html')
```

Or

add return statement inside:

```
 if request.POST.get('title') and request.POST.get('content'):
    ......

    return render(request, 'inserted.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
     content= models.TextField()
```

As you define the `title` must be unique, so you need to handle the duplicate exception and display an error message on UI side.

**view.py**

write your save post code inside try except block like:

```
try:
    post = Post()
    post.title = request.POST.get('title')
    post.content = request.POST.get('content')
    post.save()
except IntegrityError as e:
    # add your error message
```

[this](https://micropyramid.com/blog/basics-of-django-message-framework/) link will help you how to add and display an error message.

Comment: I tried but showing  this error ::  ValueError: The view firstapp.views.createpost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: one more problem facing is , if I post duplicate values through html template it showing error ::  (1062, "Duplicate entry 'django_post' for key 'title'")

Comment: You should not do this. Always redirect after a successful post.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Can you explain in more details which part should I not do this

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's not about redirect page, it's all about render page.

Comment: As I said, you should *redirect* after a post. Which is what the OP wants to do anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you read the question carefully, he wants another render page not redirect

Comment: No he doesn't; he might say that, but that's because he is inexperienced. When answering on SO you should attempt to give people guidance about how to solve their issues correctly, rather than just solving the immediate error.

Comment: I tried your method but it showing error such as ::  django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'django_post' for key 'firstapp_post_title_6d2bdecd_uniq'")

Comment: @Brahmareddy S you should add at top of the view.py script `from django.db import IntegrityError`

Answer (score 0):

You can render the `inserted.html` after successfully saving the data in database. For this, you can change your view **createpost** as:

```
def createpost(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       if request.POST.get('title') and request.POST.get('content'):
            post = Post()
            post.title = request.POST.get('title')
            post.content = request.POST.get('content')
            post.save()
            return render(request, 'inserted.html')

       return render(request, 'emp.html')
```

Comment: It showing this error such as   ValueError at /empdetails
The view firstapp.views.createpost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I thought , the problem is in html page.

Comment: your correct. but there is a small change. that change is first return  render(request,'emp.html') and second is return render(request, 'inserted.html')

Answer (score 0):

use below line to redirect to any address you like,

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("https://www.another-url.com")
```

you need to import `from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect`

Comment: how to use link ('https://www/another-url.com'') .but I have inserted.html

Comment: type the address your going to server the page on you domain http://example/page or simply add /page